# Is there an alternative to try/catch in Java for opening a file?

Tags: java, c++, file, exception, try-catch

I remember in my `c++` class we would use the following code to handle bugs when opening a file:

```
ifstream in;
in.open("foo.txt");
if(in.fail()){
   cout << "FAILURE. EXITING..." << endl;
   exit(0);
}
```

Now that I'm learning `java`, I'm having trouble using `try/catch` statements, because when I create a scanner to read my input file, it isn't recognized outside of that `try` code block. Is there any equivalent to `fail()` and `exit(0)` in `java`, or is there a better method?

Comment: use `throws` in the method you use it http://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/java-throws/

Comment: Look into variable scope.

Comment: @Dinal24 How does this prevent the use of try/catch (except you want a crashing program)? BrentAllard: Declare the variable before the try block.

Comment: C++ != Java.  Don't write Java code using C++ as guide, and don't write C++ code using Java as a guide.

Comment: Honestly, I'm much more of a C++ person, but the Java interface is nicer.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm having trouble using try/catch statements, because when I create a scanner to read my input file, it isn't recognized outside of that 'try' code block.

Good! You shouldn't be using it outside your `try` block. All of the relevant processing of the file should be *inside* the `try` block, e.g.:

```
try (
    InputStream istream = new FileInputStream(/*...*/); // Or Reader or something
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(istream)
    ) {
    // Use `scanner` here
}
// Don't use `scanner` here
```

*(That's using the newish try-with-resources.)*

In the above, I'm assuming when you said Scanner, you were specifically talking about the `Scanner` class.

Answering your actual question: No, that's just not the standard practice in Java code. Java embraces exceptions.

Comment: Why do you say that, @T.J.Crowder ? shouldn't the only cause for an exception be the actual opening of the file?

Comment: @BrentAllard: The Scanner is for reading the file, right? Or did I misunderstand? So it doesn't make sense for the scanner to exist except when reading the file.

Comment: No, that's what I'm doing with the scanner. I see what you mean, but what else could cause an exception besides the *opening* of the file?

Comment: @BrentAllard: Any file read op can cause an exception (e.g., I/O error), so all of `Scanner`'s various "next" ops could throw. But the fundamental point is: If the Scanner is for reading the file, then the only use of the scanner should be within the `try` block contingent on successfully opening the file.

Comment: @BrentAllard: If you're new to Java, it may be worth flagging up for you what that try-with-resources statement does for you: Basically, whatever you open in the `()` after `try` will automatically be closed (in reverse order) when control passes out of the `try` *for any reason* (normal execution leaving the block, an exception, etc.), and in case of an exception it closes things without letting any exceptions during the close operation obscure the primary exception that occurred. So it dramatically simplifies your code.

Answer (score 1):

To have the `Scanner` be visible outside of the `try...catch` block, just declare the variable outside of the block:

```
Scanner scanner = null;

try {
    scanner = ... //Initialize scanner
} catch (IOException e) {
    //Catch
}
```

Now you can use your scanner object outside of the `try...catch` block. To check if the initialization was successful you can check against `null` if you really have to, but usually error handling should be done inside the `catch` block, eg

```
try {
    scanner = ... //Initialize scanner
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Failure. Exiting");
    exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add throws Exception to the method in which you are using scanner.

void method_name() throws Exception{definition of method}

By this, method knows about some part of code will throw exception and needed to be handled.